# Indexing into large discontiguous ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have a large discontiguous range defined, perhaps `Range("B:B,E:E,F:F")`. How would I go about indexing into the range to treat it as if it were contiguous.

E.g. I'd like to do something like

```
Set myRange = Range("B:B,E:E,F:F")
v = myRange.ContiguousIndex(5, 3).Value 'retrieves the value in cell F5 (row 5 col 3)
```

Every method I'm aware of will offset based on the first cell in the range ("B1") and will gladly go out of the bounds of that range, spilling over into the rest of the contents of the workbook. This means that trying to access row 5, col 3 would get you D5, as if columns C and D were in the range I'm trying to index.

I've tried Range.Cells, Range.Offset, and Range.Range, but all seem to exhibit this same spillover.

The other approach I had in mind was to assign the values to a variant array and manually index from there, but this becomes complicated very quickly because a simple snippet like

```
Dim v() As Variant
v = myRange
```

will only assign the first area of the discontiguous range into the array, leaving me with an (20^20-1)x1 array and completely ignoring the rest of myRange. So it's probably doable to get the whole myRange into an array if I loop through all the areas and individually assign them into an array I keep reallocating, but it's far from easy and I end up with an array that uses far more memory than I want (unless I put more overhead into trimming it down or I arbitrarily choose a smaller number of rows to copy).

At that point, it would be far more efficient and simple to just loop through the areas manually and do the indexing myself without all the cost of putting things into an array. This final approach is what I'm currently doing.

**The Question**

Is there any existing method or trick I can use to treat myRange as if it were contiguous in the way I described and to index into myRange in a way that ignores the discontinuities?

TL;DR If I have

```
Set myRange = Range("B:B,E:E,F:F")
v = myRange.ContiguousIndex(5, 3).Value
```

I want some method ContiguousIndex to return Range("F5").Value without having to do all the work of manually checking Range.Areas and handling all the indexing.

---

***Bonus Question***

Say myRange were `Range("E:E,B:B,F:F")` (notice the different column order). Is there a nice way to treat E as the first column, B as the second, and F as the third, such that

```
Set myRange = Range("E:E,B:B,F:F")
v = myRange.ContiguousIndex(5, 2).Value 'retrieves the value in cell B5
```

returns the value of B5? This is a property of the method I'm using that I'd love to continue having.

Again, the function I have works, but I'm guessing that there's some kind of wonderful method or trick hidden away in all of Excel's quirks that would be even better.

Comment: There's no built-in method for this.

Comment: That is unfortunate.

Comment: Why would I ever want index into the rest of the sheet when I'm using a method on a specific range? It seems like the Range object should have a better concept of the cells it contains instead of seemingly tossing the problem up to its parent sheet and just computing with a relative offset. I know this is mostly just a complaint, but it seems like a bad design.

Comment: It is what it is...  Sounds like you already have some code for this though, so it's not clear whether you're looking for something other than a "built-in" method ?

Comment: So, if the index isn't found in column B, you want it to search E, then if nothing, F?  If that is how it could work, you could just wrap an `If()` statement around everything, or do `IfError()`.

Comment: Regarding the reason it works the way it does: consider the issues you'd have with areas with different numbers of columns.

Comment: @BruceWayne Unfortunately the ranges I get will be user-defined as a string and aren't guaranteed to have any sort of consistency. There could be many different areas of any number of sizes, and wrapping in IFs would be more work than just looping through range areas.

Comment: Could we possibly be working on an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?  Take a step back, and can you describe *what* you're trying to do? The user inputs a range (where?) and then you want to _______ with that range?

Comment: @DougGlancy That sort of idea is the closest reason I can come up with for why VBA doesn't have something like this already. 

E.g. my current method pretends all areas are side-by-side in a table (top-justified with variable row lengths). So if I get something like `Range("A1:B7,A8:B10")` I don't recognize that it's already contiguous, meaning I artificially turn it into a 4-column table (if that makes any sense). It's a weakness the designers probably didn't want to deal with.

Comment: To your bonus question, yes you can. `Set myRange = Range("A:A,B:B,C:C")` then create a range variable (`myCol`), and you can loop with `For each myCol in rng.Columns // myCol.select // Next myCol`

Comment: I believe the spillover is actually by design, it's a bit unintuitive but I think it is intentional. From the [`Range.Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841096.aspx) property (default property of Range object): *The RowIndex and ColumnIndex arguments are relative offsets.*

Comment: @DavidZemens Definitely agreed that this is how they designed it, though I'm not sure I agree with the design decision they made. But then, I suppose there are a number of things I dislike about their design - why should this be any different?

Comment: @mikegrann it's Microsoft, it doesn't have to make sense :P

Comment: It is handy sometimes, instead of using Offset just use the relative index. But then why did they bother adding an Offset method???

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to post up my own solution in case anyone else runs into a similar problem. This is the only one that worked for me, as the other answers and comments rely on knowing something about the Areas in the range (e.g. relying on each Area being an entire single column, which I couldn't guarantee because my ranges were user-input and could span multiple columns or a finite number of rows).

```
' Indexes into a discontiguous area as expected, ignoring cells not in Range r
' and treating areas as concatenated (and top-aligned) in the order they are specified
Public Function ContiguousIndex(r As Range, row As Long, col As Long)
    Dim area As Range

    For Each area In r.Areas
        If col <= area.Columns.count Then
            If row <= area.Rows.count Then
                ContiguousIndex = area.Cells(row, col)
                Exit Function
            Else
                Err.Raise vbObjectError + 9, , "Row Index out of bounds"
            End If
        Else
            col = col - area.Columns.count
        End If
    Next

    ' col argument > sum of all cols in all areas
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 9, , "Col Index out of bounds"
End Function
```

---

It's worth rementioning something I covered in the comments, but might be unexpected: this code will top-align all areas such that the first row in area 1 is at the same index as the first row in area 2 is the same... etc. This leads to a quirk when calling something like `ContiguousIndex(Range("A1:B7,A8:B10"), 9, 2)`. While it seems obvious this should return `B9`, this isn't the case - it will actually try to access the 9th row, 2nd column of `A1:B7`, resulting in an error. That's because the two discontiguous ranges, although they are clearly arranged top-to-bottom on the actual sheet, are treated as if they are side-to-side. So `B9` is accessible via the command `ContiguousIndex(Range("A1:B7,A8:B10"), 2, 4)` (unintuitively). This behavior is what I required, but it might not be what you expect.

In order to circumvent this, you can use the built-in [Application.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) or [Application.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030.aspx) methods. These automatically collapse contiguous regions when possible. All of the following work:

```
' Every statement will print "A1:B10" - the areas are merged

' Union of separate areas
Debug.Print Union(Range("A1:B7"), Range("A8:B10")).Address

' Union of range with a known subrange
Debug.Print Union(Range("A1:B7,A8:B10"), Range("A1:B7,A8:B10").Cells(1, 1)).Address

' Union of range with itself
Debug.Print Union(Range("A1:B7,A8:B10"), Range("A1:B7,A8:B10")).Address

' Intersect of range with itself
Debug.Print Intersect(Range("A1:B7,A8:B10"), Range("A1:B7,A8:B10")).Address
```

If this is the desired behavior when indexing, then perform one of the listed merges before calling `ContiguousIndex`. Do note that if areas are unmerged in the union operation, their relative discontiguous indices are left unchanged. E.g.

```
' Yields "A:A,F:F,C:D" not "A:A,C:D,F:F" as you might desire
Debug.Print Union(Range("A:A,F:F,C:C,D:D"), Range("A:A,F:F,C:C,D:D")).Address
```

Answer (score 2):

Something to note is that with `.Cells` / `.Rows` / `.Columns` / `._Default` you can get values outside of your range:

```
Set myRange = Range("E2:E4,C4:B2,F2:F4")   ' C4:B2 gets B2:C4 
Debug.Print myRange.Areas(2)(1).Address ' $B$2

Debug.Print myRange.Areas(2)(0, 0).Address              ' $A$1
Debug.Print myRange.Areas(2).Cells(0, 0).Address        ' $A$1
Debug.Print myRange.Areas(2).Rows(0).Columns(0).Address ' $A$1
```

If instead you index the values:

```
Debug.Print myRange.Areas(2).Value2(1, 1) ' value of B2
Debug.Print myRange.Areas(2).Value2(0, 0) ' Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

If by any chance you have areas with multiple columns like `"E:E,A:B"` it will be a bit easier to index them if you specify each column as a separate area : `"E:E,A:A,B:B"`

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your question a bit better after seeing your example. It can be "simplified" a tiny bit by enumerating the columns instead of the ranges:

```
Public Function ContiguousIndex(r As Range, row As Long, col As Long) As Range
    Dim column As Range

    For Each column In r.Columns
        If col > 1 Then
            col = col - 1
        ElseIf col = 1 Then
            If row <= column.Rows.Count And row > 0 Then
                Set ContiguousIndex = column.Rows(row)
                Exit Function
            End If
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 9, , "Row Index out of bounds"
        ElseIf col < 1 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 9, , "Column Index out of bounds"
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I could not find a way to access the enumerator directly ( for example
`r.Columns.[_NewEnum].Item(col)` does not work )

**Update**

Just for example

```
Public Function veryContiguousIndex(r As Range, row As Long, col As Long) As Range
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long: i = col * row

    For Each cell In r.Cells
        If i = 1 Then Set veryContiguousIndex = cell: Exit Function
        i = i - 1
    Next
End Function
```

then

```
Dim r As Range: Set r = [A1:B7,A8:B10]
Debug.Print r.Cells.Count; r.Columns.Count; r.Rows.Count  ' 20  2  7
Debug.Print veryContiguousIndex(r             , 9, 2).Address(0, 0) ' B9
Debug.Print veryContiguousIndex(r.EntireColumn, 9, 2).Address(0, 0) ' B9
Debug.Print veryContiguousIndex(r.EntireRow   , 9, 2).Address(0, 0) ' R1
```

Comment: I don't think this code works quite how you intend it to. For instance, given the test range `A1:B7,A8:B10` in my newer example, I'm fairly certain your code would never allow me to access cells in `A8:B10`. This is because `r.Columns` is effectively working like `r.Areas(1).Columns` and will only refer to cells from the first Area. To verify for yourself, check out `r.Columns.Count` for a range like `A1:A5,B1:F1`, which will evaluate to 1 instead of 6 as you might expect.

Comment: From the update in your answer seemed like that was intended "This behavior is what I required"

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear, but that's not so. All cells in the range still needed to be accessible in a predictable way. `B9` is still accessible if we iterate through all the areas - it's just not necessarily at the most convenient place. If we were going to limit ourselves to the first area, then we might as well have explicitly used `r.Areas(1)`. I think the idea was good and I was excited when I saw it, but Excel just treats `r.Columns` as `r.Areas(1).Columns` and it ruins everything.

Comment: Iterating over the .Cells / .Rows / .Columns / ._Default of multi-area Range with a For Each will use all of the areas. Indexing them directly ( r.Columns(2) ) will use only the first area.

Comment: Huh, I tried a different test and iterating `.Columns` does indeed go through all areas, even if `.Columns.Count` does not properly indicate how many columns there are! Apologies, my misinterpretation of how your code works led me to feed it invalid row/col arguments.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
v = myRange.Areas(2).Rows(5).Value 'retrieves the value in cell B5
```

This appears to work for the both the original and bonus questions as long as each sub-range is a single column. You could also create a simple wrapper function `ContiguousIndex(Row,Column)` in VBA to give the interface you described.

Hope that helps.